# Функция, вычисляющая произведение всех четных чисел массива

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

1. Ruby: Написать функцию, вычисляющую произведение всех четных чисел массива.
2. C использованием Active Record из таблиц cars и details (car имеет много details) нужно выбрать все машины у которых > 5 деталей

p.s ткните носом что читать и учить, чтобы с легкостью писать функции и делать грамотные запросы к БД через Active Record

Comment: Лучше под каждую из задач завести отдельный вопрос - так и ответов больше соберете и остальным посетителям искать потом ответ проще.

Comment: Хорошо, если я не ошибаюсь, то лимит 1 вопрос за 1 час, поэтому изменю чуть позже.

Comment: А у нас тут сайт помощи решения тестов для ввода в заблуждение учителей/рекрутёров/любимой_собачки?

Comment: Предлагаю топикстартеру убрать из вопроса вопрос про Active Record и задать его отдельно.

Answer (score 3):

Для вычисление произведения всех четных элементов массива можно воспользоваться следующей конструкцией

```
def even_sum(arr)
  arr.select{|x| x.even?}.inject{|res, x| res * x}
end
even_sum [1, 10, 3, 7, 2, 4] # 80
```

Здесь используется два итератора, первый `select` - отбирает четные элементы массива и возвращает новый массив с четными элементами, второй итератор `inject` пробегается по элементам массива и вычисляет их произведение (по умолчанию переменная `res` получает значение первого элемента массива). В результате последний блок возвращает значение `res`, который содержит произведение четных элементов массива

Блок `select {|x| x.even? }` может быть заменен `Proc`-вызовом `select(&:even?)`. Здесь метод `even?` стандартный метод для целочисленных значений, проверяющий число на четность (для проверки нечетных чисел предназначен метод `odd?`)

```
[1, 10, 3, 7, 2, 4].select(&:even?)
=> [10, 2, 4]
```

PS: Вариант предложенный [D-side](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181100/d-side) в комментариях предлагает использовать другую форму `inject`, принимающую символ метода (`:метод`), что эквивалентно вызову `inject` с блоком вида `{ |a, b| a.метод(b) }`. Это позволяет сократить запись ещё сильнее:

```
def even_sum(arr)
  arr.select(&:even?).inject(:*)
end
even_sum [1, 10, 3, 7, 2, 4] # 80
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44930/discussion-on-answer-by-cheops------).